# Javascript: Different background color for different div's

Tags: javascript, background, background-color

I have some troubles with javascript app to manage meetings. I have three levels of importance: 'Important', 'Medium', 'No important' and I want change background-color for them. **'Important' - red color, 'Medium' - yellow** and **'No important'-green**. I try to hold in **content** variable string from html and then compare this value with if,else if statement, but it still doesn't work. Do you have some advices?

**main.js**

```
function fetchMeetings(){
    var meetings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('meetings'));
    var meetingsResults = document.getElementById('meetingsResults');

    // Build output
    meetingsResults.innerHTML = '';
    for(var i = 0; i < meetings.length; i++){
        var date = meetings[i].date;
        var person = meetings[i].person;
        var purpose = meetings[i].purpose;
        var warning = meetings[i].warning;

        meetingsResults.innerHTML += '<div class="mettingDiv">'+
            '<h3>'+date+'</h3>'+
            '<h3>'+person+'</h3>' +
            '<h3>'+purpose+'</h3>'+
            '<h3 class="importance">'+warning+'</h3>'+
            ' <a onclick="deleteMeeting(\''+purpose+'\')" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> ' +
            '</div>';
    }

    var content= document.getElementsByClassName("importance").innerHTML;

    if(content == 'Important'){
        $('.mettingDiv').css('background-color', '#c00100');
    }
    else if(content == 'Medium'){
        $('.mettingDiv').css('background-color', '#fbff30');
    }
    else if(content == 'No important'){
        $('.mettingDiv').css('background-color', '#85ff63');
    }
}
```

[github](https://github.com/RadoszSzymon/RadoszSzymon.github.io)

[live app](https://radoszszymon.github.io/)

Ok, I tried to add additional class name to div element, but class name is still the same, code:

```
meetingsResults.innerHTML += '<div id="div1" class="mettingDiv">'+
            '<h3>'+date+'</h3>'+
            '<h3>'+person+'</h3>' +
            '<h3>'+purpose+'</h3>'+
            '<h3 class="importance">'+warning+'</h3>'+
            ' <a onclick="deleteMeeting(\''+purpose+'\')" class="btn btn-danger" href="#">Delete</a> ' +
            '</div>';
    }

    var content= document.getElementsByClassName("importance").innerHTML;

    var d = document.getElementById("div1");

    if(content == 'Important'){
        d.className += " important";
    }
```

Comment: Are you not able to set the class like <div class="mettingDiv Important"> and then just set a class for the important in your CSS file? That would save 10 lines of JS and a headache.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("importance") gives back an array of elements, so you will have to loop over them and add background color to each one's parent(div with class=mettingDiv). However it will be more cleaner if you add different class to each type of meeting while rendering only.

Comment: Try this
`meetingsResults.innerHTML += '<div class="mettingDiv ' + warning + '">'+`
this will result in `<div class="mettingDiv Important" ...`, `<div class="mettingDiv No important" ...`
and then add CSS
`
.Important { background-color: #c00100; }
.Medium { background-color: #fbff30; }
.No.important { background-color: #85ff63; }
`

Comment: Ok It's finally works. Thanks for great idea to solve this problem and have a nice weekend for all :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 meetingsResults.innerHTML += '<div class="mettingDiv ' + warning + '">'+ ...
```

this will result in `<div class="mettingDiv Important"`..., `<div class="mettingDiv No important" ...` and then add CSS

```
 .Important { background-color: #c00100; }
 .Medium { background-color: #fbff30; } 
 .No.important { background-color: #85ff63; }
```